# Making a deb package where dh doesn't build the program

Tags: debian, compiling, deb

I am trying to make a debian package for my own application, using the PBuilder utility.
I cannot use dh, because the build process of my program is very specific. When I compile it, I must run qmake instead of the usual "./configure" and then make.
So I created my own "rules" script, but when I run pdebuild, it compiles and installs the files to the desired paths, but I end up with an error saying:

```
dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute
```

My application is called Qtag, and this is my rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

clean:
    cd src; qmake
    cd src; make clean
    rm -f src/qtag
    rm -f src/Makefile

build:
    cd src; qmake
    cd src; make

build-arch: build

build-indep: build

binary-arch: build-arch
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/bin
    cp src/qtag $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/bin

binary-indep: build-indep
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/share/pixmaps
    mkdir -p $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/share/applications
    cp src/images/Qtag.png $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/share/pixmaps
    cp src/qtag.desktop $$(pwd)/debian/qtag/usr/share/applications

binary: binary-arch binary-indep
```

This is my "control" file:

```
Source: qtag
Section: unknown
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Karel Patlejch <kaja.patlejch@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), qt5-default, libtag1-dev
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: http://github.com/amethystant/qtag

Package: qtag
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, libtag1-vanilla, libqt5core5a
Description: Audio tag editor
 Qtag is a Qt-based audio tag editor. Supports ID3, Xiph Comments and more.
```

I use PBuilder and Debian 8

This is full output of pdebuild: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mZWkkv-WWpMDBwbVNwRGV4ZVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you post your `pbuilder` log somewhere? It will be in a file called something like `qtag_...build` in the parent directory of your package directory.

Comment: You should still be able to use `dh`, because it is extensively customizable. Can you post a link to your project's source code?

Comment: @FaheemMitha according to this control file (above), his source is at http://github.com/amethystant/qtag

Comment: @casey Oh, I missed that link.

Comment: @StephenKitt I can only upload it on Google Drive, but you have to download it if you want to view it. Here it is (I've also added it to the original post): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mZWkkv-WWpMDBwbVNwRGV4ZVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. Were you able to get your package working?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not yet. I was also trying to build the package using dh, but it wasn't successfull

Comment: @amethystAnt Well, maybe I can help. I'll try to keep you on my todo list. Are you able to get into the U&L chat? If so, idle there, and I'll ping you. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry, but I'd rather avoid using chat. If you know how to build the package, you can post an answer or you can donwload the source, build the package and send me a tarball with the "debian" directoy containing all the needed files

Comment: @amethystAnt sorry, I don't think such a non-interactive solution will work well. Best of luck with your packaging.

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.bugs.rc/418786 explains this message:    * binary-arch should depend on binary-${PACKAGE}, not binary-indep but not sure what this actually mean. maybe check out the commit from that package